# LESS Line Reference Comments

Tags: gruntjs, less

Is there anyway to enable line reference comments to the compiled CSS in Less?

I've researched a bit and haven't been able to find any info on how to enable line comments. This is difficult when debugging, because it's hard to know what less file the the compiled css class is coming from.

Comment: Are you looking for [`dumpLineNumbers`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-options)?

Comment: Yes!!!

Looks like you can do it with grunt as well. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#dumplinenumbers

Answer (score 1):

The help of the Less compiler will show you that you can set the `line-numbers` option

> ```
> -------------------------- Deprecated ----------------
>   --line-numbers=TYPE      Outputs filename and line numbers.
>                            TYPE can be either 'comments', which will output
>                            the debug info within comments, 'mediaquery'
>                            that will output the information within a fake
>                            media query which is compatible with the SASS
>                            format, and 'all' which will do both.
> ```

Notice that this option has been deprecated in favor of v3 CSS sourcemap, see also: [Compile LESS files with source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979732/compile-less-files-with-source-maps).