# Css path of magento

Tags: css, magento, overriding, magento2

I created custom theme and I overrided **Magento_catalog** and **css** of parent from folder Magento_catalog in blank theme. now I want to change some css code like **gallery**.I use firebug in chrome to find **path** and line css of gallery,but it shows me style.css in pub folder.how can I find exactly **path** of css??

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

As far as I know, the fastest option to do this is to search for a style in .less files. Just keep in mind that less has a syntax, so most of the times, you can't search exactly same line as you see in firebug. Usually I search for some part of the style I see in DevTools.

You can also try the complex way and run a less compilation with sourcemap

[Compile LESS files with source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979732/compile-less-files-with-source-maps)