# How to generate source map file for less files?

Tags: less

How to generate source map file for less files ?
I tried official manual. But the commands are not working

Comment: Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I.e. try to describe in details what you did exactly and how exactly you decided it's not working. Qs having nothing but "Something is not working" require a telepathy skills vastly narrowing an amount of people able to answer.

Comment: On offfical manual it says:
lessc --source-map { sourceMap: {} }
I did write this command, but response says
lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/razlet/css/--source-map{'
I dont know, why map file is not generated, why I see this error

Comment: `lessc --source-map { sourceMap: {} }` - mm, no, I'm afraid it's the docs formatting confused you. `lessc --source-map` and `{ sourceMap: {} }` are two different examples (the left is command line format, the right is JavaScript API).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile LESS files with source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979732/compile-less-files-with-source-maps)